# How to take a loop arguments from array and change them to printed signs

Tags: c

I've maid something like this. This program has to take 5 words from user, and after that, print their length as a "histogram". Problem is, how should I do this. To make a long story short, how to write an loop, to take int from every cell in word_length array, and print exactly that much "#" signs :P

```
char word_input[20];
int counter = 0;
int word_lenght[5];

while(counter < 5 )
{
    printf("Please, write a word of your choice: ");
    scanf("%20s", word_input);
    word_lenght[counter] = strlen(word_input);
    counter++;

}
printf("\n");
printf("Your histogram: \n");
for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    printf("%d.%d\n",i,word_lenght[i]);
}
```

Also, I wanted to ask here;didn't wanted to create another post. I'm doing Prata's book (also, learning git while putting every exercise there). Is it enough to start with C? I saw this: https://github.com/open-source-society/computer-science#core-applications, and I want to go through, at least everything about programming :P

Comment: `%20s` --> `%19s`

Answer (score 1):

I propose to you an idea, surely not the best but it's a start for you to think about it.

```
#define SIZE_ARRAY 5

int main(void)
{
    int word_length[SIZE_ARRAY] = {4, 2, 6, 3, 7};
    int max_value = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_ARRAY ; ++i)
    {
        if (word_length[i] > max_value)
            max_value = word_length[i];
    }

    for ( ; max_value > 0 ; max_value--)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < SIZE_ARRAY ; j++)
        {
            if (word_length[j] >= max_value)
                putchar('#');
            else
                putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return (0);
}
```